# What is the question mark in the XML attribute for?

Tags: xml, wcf

I'm looking at WCF documentation in the MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx), and have come across this wee piece of config:

```
<endpoint name="basicHttpBinding"
    address=""
    binding="basicHttpBinding"
    contract="QuickReturns.StockTrading.ExchangeService.?
        Contracts.ITradeService"/>
```

Can anyone tell me if the question mark is related to WCF, or if it's XML attribute line continuation?  I haven't found the answer yet.

Comment: The obvious answer is to try the config with the attribute all on the same line, with and without question mark, and see what works. Except that I'm troubleshooting, and I'm not able to call my services at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question mark is a typo - it shouldn't be there as it is not a valid part of type name that is being specified for the contract.

Since namespaces and types cannot begin with a question mark it is impossible that this configuration is correct as this could never be a valid CLR type name:

```
QuickReturns.StockTrading.ExchangeService.?Contracts.ITradeService
```

The question mark is some kind of mistake on MSDN (perhaps they meant to add some sort of character indicating a newline and messed up - I am not sure).  You can safely remove it and carry on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that this is a placeholder which was inserted by a text editor for a "line break marker". It shouldn't be there, remove the ? and all following whitespace (including newline) and you should be fine.